# UICI and LICI what function does SPSS use ? Prediction intervals

Tags: spss

I would like to know what SPSS does when it computes the UICI and LICI (upper and lower individual confidence interval). I am asking because when we compute "by hand" the same prediction interval for a given individual using the output tables from a simple linear regression we get a slightly different interval (up to 0,005 difference).

I couldn't find online how to get the code used for this command in order to look closer at what SPSS does when we "check" the boxes for mean and individual prediction intervals.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SPSS Algorithms manual accessible from the Help menu will give you the formulas.  Note that a confidence interval is not the same as a prediction interval.